# How to move a textview up so the keyboard doesn't block it

Tags: ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, sdk

I have several text views within a scroll view. I need some help with having the scroll view move up so the keyboard doesn't block the text view.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll the view to based on the textview rect so that it will be visible if the the keyboard pops up.

Try this when textview is ready for editing

```
-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
        CGPoint pt;
        CGRect rc = [textView bounds];
        rc = [textView convertRect:rc toView:scrollView];
        pt = rc.origin;
        pt.x = 0;
        pt.y -= 60;
        [scrollView setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];
}
```